# Can't able to get a list of rows in blobstorage tables using C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

I am trying to return a list of rows by passing column name and value. The code is shown below

```
public List<SecuritySchema> GetSecuritySchemaDetailsByProjectId(int id)
    {
        CloudTable cloudTable = GetCloudTable();
        TableQuery<SecuritySchema> securitySchemas = new TableQuery<SecuritySchema>()
                .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition(Constants.SecuritySchema.PROJECTID_COLUMN_NAME,
                 QueryComparisons.Equal, id.ToString()));
        var securitySchemaDetail = cloudTable.ExecuteQuery(securitySchemas).ToList();

        return securitySchemaDetail;
    }
```

But the count is showing 0. but in table i have 2 rows. i am using int for ProjectId in domain class.

Please help me to sort int out.

Comment: How many entities (total) are there in your table? Also, what's the data type of `PROJECTID_COLUMN_NAME` attribute?

Comment: i had give string for PROJECTID_COLUMN_NAME. 8 entities i defiend, including partitionkey,rowkey and timestamp total 11.  @GauravMantri-AIS

Comment: Thanks. How many rows are there in your table? You mentioned 2 but it was not clear if it is the total number of rows or the total number of rows matching your query.

Comment: presently there is only 2 rows. but total 11 columns are there. @GauravMantri-AIS

Comment: That's weird. Can you trace your request/response using Fiddler and see what's exactly sent across the wire? Please see if you get back continuation token (I would be very surprised if you do get that considering you only have 2 rows).

Comment: Can you double check the type of you `` column in the table storage? If it's stored as an `Int32` then you have to use `GenerateFilterConditionForInt` method instead of `GenerateFilterCondition`

Comment: @RomanKoliada thank you it got resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just summary Roman's comment to reply to help others who have same problem.

Double check the type of your column in the table storage.

If it's stored as an `Int32` then you have to use `GenerateFilterConditionForInt` method instead of `GenerateFilterCondition`.

[`GenerateFilterCondition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.tablequery.generatefiltercondition?view=azure-dotnet): Generates a property filter condition string **for the string value**.

[`GenerateFilterConditionForInt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.tablequery.generatefilterconditionforint?view=azure-dotnet): Generates a property filter condition string **for an Int32 value**.